# Is there a way to check if @Environmentobject exists swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view hierarchy where sometimes there is a chance that an @EnvironmentObject is not resolved. Is there a way to check if such @EnvironmentObject exists before accessing its value?

Something like below:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var someStateObj: SomeStateObjectType
    var body: some View {
        Button("Test") {
            // Line below will not work...
            if someStateObject != nil { /* Do Something */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should always exists, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822245/swiftui-optional-environment-object) for some possible workarounds

Comment: EnvironmentObject is a `the-must` interface contract. So *where sometimes there is a chance* - this is a bug, or `@EnvironmentObject` is a wrong instrument for this scenario.

Answer (score -2):

### For refactoring

Checking for the existence of objects wrapped by `@EnvironmentObject` in SwiftUI benefits our ability to refactor code without worrying about the runtime consequences of a missing environment object.

- We can have confidence when removing unnecessary `.environmentObject` modifiers.
- We can zero into where we must pass in an environment object.

It is not always obvious, like [when discontinuities form in the view hierarchy from extracting ToolBarItems into a ToolBarContent.](https://github.com/d108/Core-Motion-Gesture/blob/c07987108155e3b004b754ebd006ae03d7a9ba85/CoreMotionGesture/View/ContentView.swift#L94)

### Verify environment objects

We cannot use a nil check like `if someStateObject != nil` because the `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper is non-optional.

However, we can implement a check on the type for the runtime verification of an environment object as follows:

```
assert(type(of: someStateObject) == SomeStateObjectType.self)
```

### Prevent crashes from missing environment objects

- Assert in every view declaring an `@EnvironmentObject` the type declared.
- Whenever the app is run, calling the assertion will cause a failure if the environment object is missing for any reason.

For example, if we insert such a check in the child view's `init` or `.onAppear()` modifier, the assertion will catch the missing  `@EnvironmentObject` not made available during runtime by an ancestor.

Otherwise, there is no compiler warning for a missing environment object. But we can catch missing environment objects with runtime testing.

*The above answer outlines a pattern for verifying software during runtime to identify issues where a compiler check might not be sufficient.*

**I noticed that this answer had been downvoted. I would appreciate any feedback or suggestions to improve it.**

Comment: Runtime checking is just not a good solution. I would like to have a solution that prevents the app from crashing on a users device. Right now I'm avoiding environmental object for that reason.

Comment: I agree with both your points: the fact that runtime checking isn't the most effective solution, and your decision to avoid `@EnvironmentObject` if it risks causing your app to crash.